# Who (gets to) edit the FAQ?

Tags: discussion, suggestion

Who gets to edit [the FAQ](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/faq)?  The FAQ currently says:

> If your question is about …
>
> - Programming, ask on Stack Overflow.
> - Networking, servers, or maintaining other people's PCs and contains no
>     source code, ask on Server Fault.
> - General computer software or hardware troubleshooting, ask on Super
>     User.
> - Web design and HTML/CSS layout, and your job title is "designer", ask on
>     Doctype.

I'm especially concerned about the first one because this could imply people should not ask questions about plugin or theme programming which is largely what this site is about.

Maybe it could/should be (emphasis mine)?

> If your question is about …
>
> - ***General Programming not related to WordPress***, ask on Stack Overflow.
> - Networking, servers, or maintaining other people's PCs and contains no
>     source code, ask on Server Fault.
> - General computer software or hardware troubleshooting, ask on Super
>     User.
> - Web design and HTML/CSS layout, and your job title is "designer", ask on
>     Doctype.

Comment: We define the FAQ (and thus the scope of the site). It is one of [the 7 essential questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/) we should answer on this meta site. If you change your question to [the format used on WebApps](http://meta.webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/159/what-should-our-faq-contain), we can use it to start the discussion.

Comment: But who gets to *EDIT* it?  I don't seem to that the ability to do so.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this recent change, bug or whatever, but I noticed I get *edit* function under first introductory section of FAQ.

Comment: Yes, this is available to moderators on the site (just that first section though) - they're intended to edit it to reflect the scope of the site of the site once it's hashed out.